# how to sum a serie in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, sum, series

I have a serie and I do not know how to sum the elements together in my for loop.
[image]

```
for j=1:50
    E=a(j,1).*(x.^j)
    (what should I do now)
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to:

1) store each element separately and then add them together, so that you don't overwrite their values as the loop goes on.

Here is a very simple example:

```
clear
clc


a = rand(50,1); % generate dummy values for the coefficients;
n = 50;

x = 3; % dummy x value

MySum = zeros(1,n);

for Counter = 1:n

    CurrentValue = a(Counter,1)*(x^Counter); % Calculate the current value 
    MySum(Counter) = CurrentValue; % Store in an array
end

TotalSum = sum(MySum) ;% Once the loop is complete, sum all the values together.
```

This not the most efficient way. However it would allow you to access every individual sum calculated for each iteration, which could be somehow useful.

2) Alternatively, you could simply add each "Current Value" to the previous sum calculated, and then the final sum would be the last sum calculated in the loop.:

```
MySum = zeros(1,n);

CurrentSum = 0; % Initialize CurrentSum.
for Counter = 1:n

    CurrentValue = a(Counter,1)*(x^Counter)
    CurrentSum = CurrentSum + CurrentValue
end

TotalSum = CurrentSum
```

So basically your problem goes down to this:

```
E = E + a(j,1).*(x.^j)
```

That was a pretty long answer for a simple question sorry! Hope the principles of indexing and for loops is clearer for you now :)

Comment: Thank you very much dear Benoit. Very helpful and very organized.

Comment: Great then glad to help! As @Dan pointed out, vectorization is generally the way to go with Matlab. Have fun!

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness I'll add the vectorized answer:

```
j = 1:50
E=sum(A.*(x.^j)) %//Assuming you have an n-by-1 vector of coefficients call A and x is a constant
```

This way you won't need a loop at all and is generally the preferred Matlab method. You should revisit this once you've understood the basics of Matlab .

Comment: +1 for vectorizartion, but shouldn't there be a `sum`?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes there should

Answer (score 1):

```
E = 0;
for j=1:50
    E= E +a(j,1).*(x.^j);
end
```